# NHibernate Criteria engine with inner join and subquery

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

Is it posible in NHibernate to create a query that looks like this?

```
select hi.ContactId
From dbo.vw_HostInterests hi INNER JOIN
    (  Select cm1.ContactId
        From dbo.vw_ContactMoments cm1 INNER JOIN
            (
                Select Contactid
                From dbo.vw_ProfileNaw
                where GenderId = 1000
            ) as pn1 on cm1.ContactId = pn1.ContactId
        where cm1.ActivityId = 1001
    )as cm on hi.ContactId = cm.ContactId
```

where hi.ActivityId = 1038

I've managed to create the correct output with the IN statement, but I'd realy like the SQL to look like this.
The Criteria below shows part of above query with the IN Statement I used (but want to replace):

```
ICriteria criteria = DbSession.CreateCriteria<Contact>();

var dCriteria1 = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(VwHostInterest))
    .Add(Expression.Eq("ActivityId", 1038))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("ContactId")));

var dCriteria2 = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(VwContactMoment))
    .Add(Expression.Eq("ActivityId", 1001))
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("ContactId")));

criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ContactId", dCriteria1));
criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ContactId", dCriteria2));

int count = (Int32)criteria
    .SetProjection(Projections.Count("ContactId"))
    .UniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for and apologies if it isn't but my experience is that your best bet with such complex queries would be to:

a) Do this whole thing as a view and map it in NHibernate

b) Create the inner select as a view and create a mapping such that you can relate it in your query

b) Or override nhibernate (override as in skip and not in OO terms ;) and write this as a named query using native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Does that nested query produce the same result as the following?

```
SELECT hi.ContactId
FROM dbo.vw_HostInterests hi 
INNER JOIN vw_ContactMoments cm1 on hi.ContactId = cm1.ContactId
    AND cm1.ActivityId = 1001
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_ProfileNaw pn1 on pn1.ContactId = cm1.ContactId
    AND pn1.GenderId = 1000   
WHERE hi.ActivityId = 1038
```